# Which BIOS can ignore integrated graphics card and just using discrete graphics card?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia-optimus, bios

I use a laptop of GT630M, ubuntu 12.04 64 bits.

Here is my BIOS information:

```
  sam@sam:~$ sudo dmidecode -t bios
  # dmidecode 2.11
  # SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
  SMBIOS 2.7 present.

  Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
  BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: K55VM.202
    Release Date: 03/13/2012
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 6144 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        Smart battery is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 4.6

  Handle 0x0018, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
  BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 1
        en|US|iso8859-1
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

  sam@sam:~$
```

What to do next?

Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have a "Graphics" option in your BIOS: some models allow the discrete graphics card to take control of the system to be compatible with older versions of Microsoft Windows.

You may also consider installing Bumblebee to be able to use the discrete graphics card throught the integrated card:
http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu

If bumblebee is not stable for your system, it's worth reporting the issue as explained here: http://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Reporting-Issues

Comment: Is bumblebee stable? I have tried bumblebee but my system seems unstable.It sometimes will freeze(I can't type or move cursor).

Comment: If bumblebee is not stable for your system, it's worth reporting the issue as explained here: http://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Reporting-Issues